# ionic wordpress rest api register is secure

Tags: wordpress, rest, security, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

i have register page in ionic that communicating with wordpress rest api, for register new user by api it needs admin access 
for admin access i should post admin user and pass then by admin revised token send  registration user request

but i want ask about secure of this method, when sending admin user pass through the app can it sniffed ?
 i think in this method admin user pass can easily sniff

i'm not test it but i'm not sure about security sending admin data
please guide about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic is a client-side framework. Anything stored on or sent from/to the client is known to the user, and you can do nothing about this apart from making it somewhat harder. The user can be assumed to have full control of the client device, be it a pc, a mobile phone or whatever else.

So for you design to work and based on your description, you have to store the Wordpress admin username and password on the client. This is clearly insecure, your users will be able to extract it from the Ionic app itself, or even easier, when it gets sent to the server, as you correctly discovered.

The solution is to have a server-side component that will hold the Wordpress credentials for you, and your Ionic app would talk to your server only. This would effectively mitigate the Wordpress admin credentials issue, but you need another server.

Also note that using such a server, anybody will still be able to act like your Ionic app, and register users in Wordpress. You should not assume that it's only your Ionic client that can do this, because as stated above, anything known to the client is known to the user, who can create arbitrary requests, indistinguishable from your Ionic client requests. But with this new server in the design, at least the Wordpress admin credentials will not be disclosed, and any functionality not exposed by your server will not be available to endusers.